# Allowing final fields to take default values

Tags: java, final

I am writing a parser for a binary file format. I have created classes to represent the deserialized structures I am reading, in which I would like to use *final* variables to hold the extracted data.

```
class MyObject {
    final int my_x;
    final int my_y;
    final int my_z;
}
```

The bump I am running into is that the presence of certain fields depends on certain flags being set. For example:

```
MyObject(InputStream is) {
    my_x = in.read();
    if (my_x == 1) {
        my_y = in.read();
        if (my_y == 1) {
            my_z = in.read();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gives me an error because **my_y** and **my_z** may not be initialized. These conditionals can be 5-6 levels deep, and I don't want to track which fields may not be read at each level of the branch tree. Another complication is that, based on certain flags, there may be subobjects that I would like to handle with the same pattern as the top-level structures.

```
class MyObject {
    final int my_x;
    final SubObject my_subobject;

    MyObject(InputStream is) {
        my_x = is.read();
        if (my_x == 1)
            my_subobject = new SubObject(is);
    }

    class SubObject {
        final int sub_x;
        final int sub_y;

        SubObject(InputStream is) {
            sub_x = is.read();
            if (sub_x == 1)
                sub_y = is.read();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make my fields final without twisting the code to handle each possible combination of flags?

Comment: Are you really sure that making those fields final is a good idea? You could make them private and provide only getters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use local variables and assign to the `final` fields at the end of the constructor.

```
public MyObject(InputStream is) {
    int x = default_x_value;
    int y = default_y_value;
    int z = default_z_value;
    x = in.read();
    if (x == 1) {
        y = in.read();
        if (y == 1) {
            z = in.read();
        }
    }
    my_x = x;
    my_y = y;
    my_z = z;
}
```

Alternatively (as Jon Skeet suggests in his comment), use a static factory method that computes the appropriate values for a no-default constructor:

```
public static MyObject makeMyObject(InputStream is) {
    int x = default_x_value;
    int y = default_y_value;
    int z = default_z_value;
    x = in.read();
    if (x == 1) {
        y = in.read();
        if (y == 1) {
            z = in.read();
        }
    }
    return new MyObject(x, y, z);
}
```

A third approach would be to define an initializer object class:

```
public class MyObject {
    private static class MyObjectInitializer {
        int x = default_x_value;
        int y = default_y_value;
        int z = default_z_value;
        MyObjectInitializer(InputStream is) {
            x = in.read();
            if (x == 1) {
                y = in.read();
                if (y == 1) {
                    z = in.read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public MyObject(InputStream is) {
        this(new MyObjectInitializer(is));
    }
    private MyObject(MyObjectInitializer init) {
        my_x = init.x;
        my_y = init.y;
        my_z = init.z;
    }
}
```

The initializer class may have utility on its own, in which case you could make it (and the corresponding `MyObject` constructor) public.

Comment: Or use a static factory method which calls the constructor when it's done all the actual work.

Comment: I considered this approach, but my object may have tens or even hundreds of fields, and this would make my factory/constructor/class very long and hard to read.

Comment: You could use this approach and make it clearer by using the builder pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: @user2363399 - I added a third approach that might help separate the complexity of initialization from the essentials of the class. At the end of the day, however, having hundreds of fields with highly complex and interdependent initialization logic is going to result inevitably in code that is long and hard to read. Your only choice is where to put the complexity.

Comment: I've decided to opt for the builder. It has tripled my code size with redundant statements, but it seems this is simply a limitation of Java.